# How to color rows depending on data values Yii CGridView

Tags: php, css, ajax, yii, cgridview

I have Users model.

Displaying it with CGridView i want to color the rows depending on `$model->is_admin` which is an integer either 0 or 1, so either of 2 colors.

Could it be done by simple settings of CGridView ?

**Controller**

```
/**
* Lists all models.
*/
public function actionIndex() {
    $model = new Users('search');
    $model->unsetAttributes();  // clear any default values
    if (isset($_GET['Users']))
        $model->attributes = $_GET['Users'];

    $this->render('index', array(
        'model' => $model,
    ));
}
```

**View**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 table-responsive">
        <?php
        $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
            'id' => 'users-grid',
            'itemsCssClass' => 'table table-bordered table-hover dataTable',
            'dataProvider' => $model->search(),
            'enablePagination' => false,
            // 'filter'=>$model,
            'columns' => array(
                'username',
                'first_name',
                'last_name',
                'email',
                ),
                array(
                    'class' => 'CButtonColumn',
                ),
            ),
        ));
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What have your tried?

Comment: CGridView::rowCssClassExpression.

Comment: may have gotten stuff wrong with it

Comment: You shoudl show us some code, or we can't help you.

Comment: Controller /**
     * Lists all models.
     */
    public function actionIndex() {
        $model = new Users('search');
        $model->unsetAttributes();  // clear any default values
        if (isset($_GET['Users']))
            $model->attributes = $_GET['Users'];

        $this->render('index', array(
            'model' => $model, 
        ));
    }

Comment: View $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
                                    'id' => 'users-grid',
                                    'itemsCssClass' => 'table table-bordered table-hover dataTable',
                                    'dataProvider' => $model->search(),
                                    'enablePagination' => false,
                                    // 'filter'=>$model,
     'columns' => array(
      'username',
      'first_name',
          array(
         'class' => 'CButtonColumn',
        ),
               ),
                                ));

Comment: please edit that into yor question. As a comment it's not readable at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a good looking example which may help you:

http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/314/cgridview-use-special-variable-data-in-the-htmloptions-of-a-column-i-e-evaluate-htmloptions-attribute/

I had no luck implementing it by myself, using only build-in features, so it might be the only option.
I did not try this one, but as comments say, it should work.

**EDIT:**
I made it, much shorter way

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'dataProvider' => $data_provider,
    'rowCssClassExpression' => '$data["is_admin"] ? "tr_isadmin" : ""',
    'columns' => array(
        array(
            'header' => 'Is admin?',
            'name' => 'is_admin',
        ),
    ),
);
```

So, rowCssClassExpression adds a class for tr wrapper based on $data["is_admin"] value.

Then, simply add css like

```
.tr_isadmin { 
    background-color: red; 
}
```

Of course, it is just simplified example. You have to adapt it for your purpose.

Comment: on mouse over, it reverts to original color??

Comment: Feel free to test it and let me know

Comment: can't seem to override hover css.

Comment: .grid-view table.items tr:hover.selected
{
 background: #CCFF66;
}

Comment: is default hover css